# My attempt of Baby Rudin exercise 4.2

Tags: analysis

> If $f$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, prove that $$f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)} $$
> for every set $E\subset X$. ($\overline{E}$ denotes the closure of $E$.)

My attempt:

Let $x \in \overline{E}$. We need to show that $f(x) \in \overline{f(E)}$. Then x is either in E or x is not in E but x is the limit point of E.

Case (i): x is in E. Then obviously $f(x) \in f(E) \subset \overline{f(E)}$.

Case (ii): x is not in E and x is a limit point of E. Then I am stuck. How to continue?

I know there are other methods. I don't need other solution. I just want to know how to complete the proof along my thinking.

Comment: If $x \in \bar{E}$ is a limit of sequence $x_n \in E$, then what can be said about $f(x)$?

Comment: Since f is continuous at x, it is equivalent to saying for any sequence $\{x_j\}$ which converges to x,  $\{ f(x_j)\}$ converges to f(x)

Comment: Exactly, so since $f(x)$ is a limit of $f(x_n)$ where every $x_n$ is in $E$, then what does it implies about $f(x)$? It is not only in $f(E)$ but also in... ?

Comment: It implies f(x) is a limit point of f(E), thus $f(x) \in \overline{f(E)}$

Comment: Yes, so we're done, right?

Comment: yes, thank you!